# File path access permission

Tags: file, uwp

I want to access a folder other than root folders in UWP. The user will select the file with a file picker and then this file will be used for software update.

I am able to provide file selection as below. Then when I read this file, I get the error that I do not have permission to access it.

```
    var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bin");

    file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(file.Path);
    StorageFile storageFile =  await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(file.Name);
    var fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(storageFile.Path, FileMode.Open);
```

If I manually copy the folder to the root folder and it works fine with the code below.

```
    StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile storageFile =  await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(file.Name);
    var fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(storageFile.Path, FileMode.Open);
```

Solution for me in two ways. The first is to copy files from the outside to the root folder, the second way is to eliminate the access permission problem.Since it is a constantly changing file, I cannot import it into the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uwp has strong file access restriction, `File.open` is not uwp api, it can only access two location, which are **Application install directory** and **Application data locations**, so your code works well when you copy this file to Application data location. Therefore, I suggest you could use [StorageFile.OpenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.openasync?view=winrt-20348) method instead of File.open() to get the stream.